# AutoComplete in Android

Tags: android

I am developing an application where a list of words are shown..The list very big and user can select any one of the items in the list..I would like to provide search functionality where user can type in a keyword(part of the word) and a only matching items need to be displayed..Any idea of how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Well... the AutoCompleteTextView has been a part of the Android API since day 1... it does exactly what you need. You'll have to have your list items in some kind of adapter, but that shouldn't be too difficult to implement.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html

Edit - And indeed, look at Sanjay's post for a link to a tutorial on using it.